# How to implement filter in non VO-based ADF RichTable?

Tags: java, filter, oracle-adf

I need to populate a table using a programmatically populated ArrayList, and my requirement is to have a filter function for that table.
However, I have not found any tutorial on this, since most tables use VOs to populate their data.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this very easy:

Make a bean, insert a getter and setter for your arraylist and convert your bean to a DataControl. That way you can just use it as an VO (drag & drop , ...).
Including tables with filter.